# UPDATE value if more than 0, how?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `hiho`=`hiho`+2 WHERE 1
```

It will give all users +2 in 'hiho'. I want to change it, to add +2 hiho but only when user got more than 0 in hiho.
Is possible in SQL query?

Comment: `where \`hiho\` > 0`?

Comment: Nothing to reproduce here!

Answer (score 2):

Use proper where condition

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `hiho`=`hiho`+2 
WHERE `hiho` > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

in case there are empty `hiho` rows

```
update `users` set `hiho`=`hiho`+2 where `hiho` not in(0,"");
```